# sequences and mathematical induction to proove its a cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis

so i have a problem with analysis how am i able to prove that
$$|a_m - a_{m-1}| \leq \frac{1}{2}|a_n -a_{n-1}|$$ is a cauchy sequence? for all natural numbers $n >1$.
the first part is where there is mathematical induction where you have to prove that for all $m\geq n>1$, $$|a_m - a_{m-1}|<= 2^{n-m}|a_n-a_{n-1}|$$
I do not know where to go from there

Comment: Please use proper capitalization, punctuation, and grammar. Using separate lines would make this much more readable. I see that you tried some linebreaks, but this site uses the common standard that two linebreaks (an empty white line) are needed for a newline.

Answer (score 1):

$|a_m-a_n|=|(a_m-a_{m-1})+(a_{m-1}-a_{m-2})+...+(a_{n+1}-a_n)|$
Now break up the right-hand side.